# Virtuemart email notification not working

Tags: joomla, payment, virtuemart

we re using Virtuemart2 with joomla for our eCommerce website,if we   are using the standard payment in virtue mart, both of the vendor and   shopper gets their email notification properly.But when we using MIGS   payment we didn't get the email notification.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem normally occurs, when the setting for the order status after the payment is not set properly inside of the payment configuration.

Inside of the payment configuration, the standard statusses are "pending", "confirmed by shopper" and "confirmed" and so on. If it is a payment system like Paypal, where the payment is finalized right away, the returning status should be "confirmed".

In VirtueMart configuration there is a tab where you can select the statusses at which to send a mail. I think, the tab was called "Checkout". In VM 3.0.14 and above, the tab is called "Emails". Here you have to adjust the settings according to the status after payment(s).

Please keep you VM at the latest version 2.6.22, and Joomla at 2.5.28 including the fix from 21st Dec 2015 to address all security issues.